# Error while installing "python get-pip.py"

Tags: python, pip

FYR- Logs below.

```
C:\Users\la26519\Desktop>python get-pip.py
Downloading/unpacking pip
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pip
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\la26519\pip\pip.log
```

Please let me know for any workaround and assist for successful installation.

When queried the pip.log, i got the following

```
Downloading/unpacking pip Getting page pypi.python.org/simple/pip
Could not fetch URL pypi.python.org/simple/pip: connection error:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries
exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>:
[Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed) Will skip URL
pypi.python.org/simple/pip when looking for download links for pip
```

Comment: When queried the pip.log, i got the following
Downloading/unpacking pip
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: connection error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed)
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/ when looking for download links for pip

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Answer (score 4):

Turn off any proxy / fiddler / other developer tool that redirect traffic.

Worked for me.